# Fade Out Old Image and Fade In New for List Item Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sprite image for each list item (home, services and contact). I'm using CSS to move the position on hover. It works fine except I would like fade the transition instead of rapidly moving the position. I am trying to make it look like the button is being pushed in on hover. I would like to slow it down. I have been all day on this and not getting anywhere. Thanks for any help!

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li class="link1"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="link2"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li class="link3"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li.link1 {
text-indent: -9999px;
background-image: url(../images/home.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 15px;
width: 66px;
background-position: left top;
}
li.link1:hover {
background-image: url(../images/home.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 15px;
width: 66px;
background-position: left bottom;   
}
li.link2 {

Repeats itself...
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with a sprite...

Comment: Then I can change it to two images if that solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a test case for us to see somewhere?

Comment: Can you upload your code to a server somewhere and send us the link so we can see what you're code currently does?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to make it look like the button is being pushed in on hover, you don't need images for that.  You can do that purely with CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do it with relative positioning and CSS3 transitions?

```
li.link1 {
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(http://www.rjdesigns.net/temp/images/home.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 15px;
    width: 66px;

     transition: margin 0.25s;
     -moz-transition: margin 0.25s; /* Firefox 4 */
     -webkit-transition: margin 0.25s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -o-transition: margin 0.25s; /* Opera */
}

li.link1:hover {
    background-position: left bottom;

    // These lines add height to the top of the li, so it doesn't 
    // glitch/vibrate if you hover on the top pixel or two
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    top: -2px;

    // Increase margin by 2px on top and left
    // Decrease by 2px on right so you don't shift other menu items
    margin: 2px -2px 0 22px !important;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gP9kD/

Update Demo with all three links and simplified CSS for the `li` elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gP9kD/1/

**jQuery**

If you want a true `fade` effect, you can do this with jQuery.  I hacked together an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/gP9kD/4/

This example creates clones of each `li` changes the background-positioning, and absolutely positions them under the current `li` elements and hides them.  Then on hover, it fades the main `li` out (to almost zero, so it still stays active), and fades in the one underneath.

It is a little hacky, because the `li` clones still contain the link, etc.  But it works, and demonstrates the principle.

Comment: Hmm, oddly, there seems to be a bug with transition on both top and left at the same time, even though I found documentation of such.  Try the edit above using `margin`, and see my demo.

Comment: See jQuery example as well for a true fade.